# Why this theory is consistent?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm **not** asking how to do these exercises. But I'm very confused about a thing.

**Question**: By hypothesis $T$ is an axiomatization of the class of $L$-structure with an even cardinality. So if $\mathcal{M} $ is a model of $T$ then it has an even cardinality. Also $T_{\infty} $ is an axiomatization of the class of $L$-structure that are infinite. So how it is possible that $T \cup T_{\infty} $ is consistent? Said in an ugly way: how can infinity be even?

Let $L$ a language consisting only with the symbol equal. And consider any $L$-theory $T$ for which its models are exactly the structure with an even cardinality.

1. Find a theory $T_{\infty}$ whose models are exactly the $L$-structure whose domain is infinite.
2. Prove that $T \cup T_{\infty} $ is consistent.
3. What are the cardinaities of the domains of models of the theory $T \cup T_{\infty} $
4. Prove that every infinite $L$-structure is a model of $T \cup T_{\infty}$ and deduce that every infinite $L$-structure is a model of $T$.

**My reasoning**:  I proved that $T \cup T_{\infty} $ is finitely satisfiable, then by compactness theorem it is satisfiable. Okay, true! But I'm struggling to understand how it is possible that a model of $T \cup T_{\infty} $ could even exist. A model $ \mathcal{M} $ of $T \cup T_{\infty} $ has to be also a model of $T_{\infty} $ and a model of $T$ since $ T, T_{\infty} \subseteq T \cup T_{\infty} $. Since $ \mathcal{M} $ is a model of $T_{\infty}$ has to be infinite, since  $ \mathcal{M} $ is a model of $T$ it has to be even. It seems to me more a proof of the fact that $T \cup T_{\infty}$ is not consistent.
Clearly, if an infinite model exists then by downward Löwenheim–Skolem Theorem and by the fact the language is finite, then we have a countable model, then by upward Löwenheim–Skolem Theorem we have that every infinite model is model of $T \cup T_{\infty} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem (overspill principle).
If a set of sentences has arbitrarily large finite models, then it has a denumerable model.

Proof sketch. For each $n$, add a sentence which is true in and only in models of size $\geq n$. Then apply the compactness theorem.

Corollary.
There exists no set of statements $T$ s.t. all of its models have even (and thus finite) cardinality and for every even number $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it has a model of cardinality $n$, since then $T$ would also have a denumerable model.

Comment: I think then that who wrote the exercises did a typo. $T$ is a theory for which its **finite** models are exactly the structure of even cardinality. Then it is not an axiomatization of the structure of even cardinality and possesses also infinite models. With this modification, it is possible for $T \cup T_{\infty} $ to have models with finite cardinality? I would say no.

Comment: @3m0o An example of such T is "∀x∀y Rxy↔Ryx", "∀x ¬Rxx", "∀x∃!y Rxy". And let $T_\infty$ be a set of sentences that uses no nonlogical symbols other than the equality symbol s.t. its models are precisely those that have infinite cardinality. With this example, $T \cup T_\infty$ sure will be consistent.

Comment: I don't think this work since $R$ is the symbol $=$ since $L$ contain only the symbol $=$ and $T$ is a $L$-theory, so $ \forall x Rxx $. Anyway i was saying another things. A such $T$ exsits, but is not axiomatizable with finitely sentences, and its models are infinite and with even cardinality. But the models of  the consistent $T \cup T_{\infty} $ are only those with infinite cardinality.

Comment: For example $T = \{ \varphi_2, \neg \psi_{2n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N}   \} $, where $ \varphi_2 : \exists x_1 \exists x_2  \neg x_1 = x_2 $ , and $ \psi_{k} : \exists x_0 \ldots \exists x_k  ( \left( \bigwedge_{ 1 \leq i \neq j \leq k} \neg x_i = x_j   \right) \wedge \forall z \left( \bigvee_{1 \leq j \leq k} z = x_j \right) )  $.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that $T$ is an $L$-theory and $L$ only has $=$.